# I need advice about how to make multi_language site using codeigniter and manage database, model and controller for this site

Tags: database, codeigniter, model-view-controller, localization

I make an admin panel and I would like to do multi-language admin panel for English and Arabic, I make the language file inside language directory and make switch between these file depend on admin choose that works correctly the question is how to structure the codeigniter (controller,model,database) to manage the admin panel for example if I have the categories how to make controller model and database suitable to the language data ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please read how to ask questions on the site, or your question will be down voted ...etc, people will ask you to show some code  and what have you tried so far and the sort ,  as for your question quickly I would use the database for that like prestashop does http://www.prestashop.com/images/blog/mpd-large.gif

Comment: there is also a second aproach using codeigniter language class , see https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html